# is it possible to use smart image in multi-composite field?

Tags: dialog, aem

I tried using smart image in multi composite field. In that the images are getting persisted, the remaining fields in the multi composite fields are not getting persisted. when i edited the dialog for the first time the values are getting stored on the node. when i edit the dialog next time it is showing me empty fields for the fields other than smart image.

Comment: Even if you can do it somehow, you shouldn't. User experience would be terrible. Refactor your component into a paragraph system and put small image components into it.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. SmartImage and SmartFile have some restrictions to them. And there are two different versions: SmartImage and SmartFile vs. Html5SmartImage and Html5SmartFile. Depending on your actual Version of CQ it is even only possible to have the smartimage as a separate tab without any other fields. On top of that the behaviour for the different browser and versions together with the configuration of your SmartImage have different outcomes in JCR. This is even true for AEM 5.6.1 and the Html5 versions of the the xtype.

I can't post the full solution (as the code is not mine) but give some pointers how you could achieve your requirement:
Write your own Widget that replaces the multifield xtype. The author called it genericmultifield and what it does is to open an additional configurable dialog for each item. In this dialog you have the full controll again. It stores each item as a separate node below your resource from where you open your main dialog.

Though you need good ExtJs knowledge to achieve this and considering AEM 6, with a complete new Touch UI I am not sure if it is wise to do so. I didn't have time to check out AEM6, but maybe they already have something like this in their new UI.